# Is the phrasing of "Su cama es menos larga que mi cama, pero, su armario es más largo que mi armario" OK?

Tags: gramática

Is this phrase grammatically correct? I'm not sure if I have the masculine/feminine articles correct. Can I say it like this?

> Su cama es menos larga que mi cama, pero, su armario es más largo que
>   mi armario.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase is right, but is hard to find somebody using it that way in regular conversation. Please consider:

> Su cama es más chica que la mía, pero su armario es más grande que el
>   mío.

*Armario* is rather rare in Latin America. Consider *clóset* or *ropero*.

Comment: In Spain, "*armario*" is the usual term.

Comment: I think that "*más pequeña*" is more used in Spain than "*más chica*". Anyhow, both indicate "smaller" which is not exactly the same as "menos larga", so I'd suggest using "*menos larga*" or "*más corta*" instead.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, the sentence is correct but sounds a bit odd to native speakers.  I would suggest the use of possessive pronouns as follows, and changing some words as follows:

> Su cama es más corta que la mía, pero su armario es más grande.

(that is for Castilian Spanish).